# Not getting proper file path using c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display some image which are fetching from database using c# asp.net but i am getting some error.

> Error:
>
> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> C:\ASP project\Odiya_Doctor_Client\Odiya_Doctor_Client\ODIYA_Doctor_Admin\Upload\Banner\2015-07-09_01-50-41-PM_Medical-banner-with-icons.jpg
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\ASP project\Odiya_Doctor_Client\Odiya_Doctor_Client\ODIYA_Doctor_Admin\Upload\Banner\2015-07-09_01-50-41-PM_Medical-banner-with-icons.jpg

I am explaining my code below.

**index.aspx:**

```
<img runat="server" id="imgCtrl" src='<%# resizeAndConvertToBase64("/ODIYA_Doctor_Admin/Upload/Banner/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("Bnr_Image")),1920,680) %>' class="ls-bg" />
```

index.aspx.cs:

```
protected string resizeAndConvertToBase64(string imageDirectory, int newWidth, int newHeight)
        {
            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(imageDirectory));
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

            }
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
            var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            return "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Data;
        }
```

Actually i want to access one image which is present inside `c:\ASP\ODIYA_Doctor_Admin\Upload\Banner` folder but here my inde.aspx page is inside `c:\ASP\Odiya_Doctor_Client\Odiya_Doctor_Client` folder. In the error message the path is coming `C:\ASP project\Odiya_Doctor_Client\Odiya_Doctor_Client\ODIYA_Doctor_Admin\Upload\Banner\2015-07-09_01-50-41-PM_Medical-banner-with-icons.jpg` and from this path i want to remove `\Odiya_Doctor_Client\Odiya_Doctor_Client`. So please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: why don't you include the image in your solution.

Comment: the path: /ODIYA_Doctor_Admin/Upload/Banner/ is the root folder of the solution, type the whole filepath: C:\....etc...

Comment: @Amit: it fetching the wrong path.Actually i want to move out from root folder and access image from another folder which is present inside c:/ASP project.

Comment: @Cageman: I know that but i dont want to use the whole path.Let me to edit the back end code of index page in my post.

Comment: you might be interestd in `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Amit: Can you edit your answer.

Comment: If the image location is not in your solution file, it is better to put full path rather than mappath

Comment: @dada: If i am giving the full path at the time of publish it might create problem again.

Comment: the problem is here in your file path `resizeAndConvertToBase64("/ODIYA_Doctor_Admin/Upload/Banner/"`
how will .net know where to find `/odiya` if it is not in your solution file?

Comment: @dada : So what should be the correct path.

Comment: create a folder in your solution that has a name of `/ODIYA_Doctor_Admin/Upload/Banner/`

Comment: If you want to keep these file out of solution then i would suggest create a configurable app settings with base address so that you can change it later when ever required. Because you have to define coomplete path.

Comment: @dada: Actually i want to move back from this project folder and access image from another folder.

Comment: ahh ok. so use fileupload control from asp.net controls. and do not use server.mappath. use the complete path from fileupload control

Comment: Hi @satya try the answer i have posted.

Comment: @Anupam: Your answer is really useful.Thanks...This way is always good.

Comment: @Satya, If its good then i would recommend you to accept that as answer so that other can also be get benefited.

Comment: @Anupam:Ok i will do that.But tell me one thing is this possible to get out from root project and access image from another project with out set any path in .config file.You know we are using ../  for client side image tag like this any other way to do this in asp.net ?

Comment: See you can access resources within your solution folder using Server.MapPath. But when you are going outside of your solution folder, you have to define complete path. Your application doesn't have any idea outside your solution folder. So if you want to access anything placed outside your solution folder you have to define complete path. Its not about only asp.net, you can see in all web tech.

Comment: did you try my answer? using fileupload control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would suggest you to do this way:

1. Create a application setting:

      <appSettings >
        <add key="ImgFolderPath" value="c:\ASP\ODIYA_Doctor_Admin\Upload\Banner"/>
      </appSettings>
2. Change your aspx code:

    <img runat="server" id="imgCtrl" src='<%# resizeAndConvertToBase64( Convert.ToString(Eval("Bnr_Image")),1920,680) %>' class="ls-bg" />

3. Change your .cs page code:


protected string resizeAndConvertToBase64(string imageName, int newWidth, int newHeight)
            {
                Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImgFolderPath"].ToString();
                System.Drawing.Image srcImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path+"/"+imageName));
                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
                {
                    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

                }
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
                    var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                    return "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Data;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

use fileupload control for file location instead of server.mappath
because server.mappath always looking at your solution folder

```
private void getPicture()
 {
      string location = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
      resizeAndConvertToBase64(location, 100,100);
 }

 protected string resizeAndConvertToBase64(string imageDirectory, int newWidth, int newHeight)
    {
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        System.Drawing.Image srcImage = imageDirectory;
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

        }
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
        var base64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        return "data:image/gif;base64," + base64Data;
    }
```